# Potential Bug in MATLAB regress R2014a

Tags: matlab, debugging, regression

MATLAB R2014a used to work fine w regress but now I get an error when the variables are fine and rank is satisfactory.

```
X = rand([10 3])

X =

    0.8407    0.3517    0.0759
    0.2543    0.8308    0.0540
    0.8143    0.5853    0.5308
    0.2435    0.5497    0.7792
    0.9293    0.9172    0.9340
    0.3500    0.2858    0.1299
    0.1966    0.7572    0.5688
    0.2511    0.7537    0.4694
    0.6160    0.3804    0.0119
    0.4733    0.5678    0.3371

K>> Y = rand([10 1])

Y =

    0.1622
    0.7943
    0.3112
    0.5285
    0.1656
    0.6020
    0.2630
    0.6541
    0.6892
    0.7482


[B,BINT] = regress(Y,X)

Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.

Error in regress (line 93)
b(perm) = R \ (Q'*y);
```

Obviously, X and Y are fine. There's something wrong w/ the matrix math in regress and it's that perm is, for some reason, being output as a vector (giving an ind error).  A few lines above, qr is called like this with no further modification to perm:

```
[Q,R,perm] = qr(X,0);
```

Help file says qr is supposed to output a third argument that's a matrix - but how can that be if the math always expects a vector?

```
%   [Q,R,E] = QR(A) produces unitary Q, upper triangular R and a
%   permutation matrix E so that A*E = Q*R. The column permutation E is
%   chosen so that ABS(DIAG(R)) is decreasing.
```

Very confusing considering both of these are built-in functions. I literally re-installed MATLAB R2014a and a few toolboxes and STILL get this error. It feels like qr got updated to output a different argument, but I don't understand why a fresh reinstall wouldn't take care of this, or why qr would have updated at all anyways. Everything else in my MATLAB is great.

Any ideas???

Comment: I cannot reproduce this issue. Have you perhaps messed with built-in functions?

Comment: sounds like an SVD issue, I got no error with matlab 2017b. Can you try it with newer svd?

Comment: `regress` doesn't call `QR(A)`, it calls `QR(A,0)`. From the help for `QR`: `[Q,R,E] = qr(A,0) produces an "economy size" decomposition in which E is a permutation vector, so that A(:,E) = Q*R.`. Called in this way, the third output argument is always a vector.

Comment: As far as I know, nothing changed about `regress` or `qr` in releases of MATLAB close to R2014a. I would guess that you may have another function on the path that is conflicting with a built-in. Try typing e.g. `which -all regress` or `which -all qr` to check.